# How can you set the SMTP envelope MAIL FROM using System.Net.Mail?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

When you send an email using C# and the System.Net.Mail namespace, you can set the "From" and "Sender" properties on the MailMessage object, but neither of these allows you to make the MAIL FROM and the from address that goes into the DATA section different from each other.  MAIL FROM gets set to the "From" property value, and if you set "Sender" it only adds another header field in the DATA section.  This results in "From X@Y.COM on behalf of A@B.COM", which is not what you want.  Am I missing something?

The use case is controlling the NDR destination for newsletters, etc., that are sent on behalf of someone else.

I am currently using [aspNetEmail](http://www.aspnetemail.com/) instead of System.Net.Mail, since it allows me to do this properly (like most other SMTP libraries).  With aspNetEmail, this is accomplished using the EmailMessage.ReversePath property.

Answer (score 7):

`MailMessage.Sender` will always insert a `Sender` header (interpreted as *on behalf of* in your e-mail client).

If you use the `Network` delivery method on the `SmtpClient`, `.Sender` will also change the sender in the envelope. Using the `PickupDirectoryFromIis` delivery method will leave it to IIS to determine the envelope sender, and IIS will use the `From` address, not the `Sender` address.

[There's a similar question on MSDN here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/a26c273a-18eb-4143-8631-233088977b21/)

Answer (score 4):

I just found how to do it:

- mail.From specify the email from visible to the final user
- mail.Sender specifies the envelope MAIL FROM

That's it (even if it took me a while to figure it out)

Comment: No, as mentioned in my question: and if you set "Sender" it only adds another header field in the DATA section. This results in "From X@Y.COM on behalf of A@B.COM", which is not what you want.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was analyzing the packets using Wireshark and the envelope MAIL FROM was correctly set. I did not see any issue using GMail or AOL (sender, from, to and return-path are correctly set). 
But when I use my hotmail account or my exchange server, I see the same message as you do.

Comment: It's not about hiding the sender. The issue is that the mail envelope is technically not part of the message itself, and that the Return-Path header is surrounded by many complex considerations. This means the actual delivery method will have an impact on both of these.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the following lines the Return-Path and the Reply-To headers are set in the mail header.

```
Dim strReplyTo As String = "email@domain.tld"
message.ReplyToList.Add(strReplyTo)
message.Headers.Add("Return-Path", strReplyTo)
```

And if you click on reply the e-mail set to the Reply-To address

Comment: +1. I tested with Outlook, seems to be working. I wonder though if one can be 100% sure that all email clients respect the `Reply-To` header and reply to the address given in that header.

Comment: Return-Path will not work in header . It will always take bounce email address even your sender or your from address in system.net.mail .

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?:

```
//create the mail message
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

 //set the addresses
 mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com");
 mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com");

 //set the content
 mail.Subject = "This is an email";
 mail.Body = "this is a sample body with html in it. <b>This is bold</b> <font color=#336699>This is blue</font>";
 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

 //send the message
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
 smtp.Send(mail);
```

From http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.2.aspx

Comment: No, the mail.From address will determine the MAIL FROM in the envelope and in the DATA section.  I want to make those two different addresses.

Comment: the mail.From address will not necessarily determine the MAIL FROM in the envelope. It depends on the delivery method.